# STM32F407 Uart Rx inturrupts misses some characters

Tags: uart, stm32f4

UART sometimes lost some characters while communicate with all other devices.

I tried communication with arduino, serial monitor(At PC, with serial-usb converter), HM-10 Bluetooth module.

In every case, my stm32f407 misses some characters when receive data.
(I checked it with LCD. I don't send any data with uart.)
For example, when I send send "This is test string" from PC,
The incoming string is like "Ths is tt sring".
There are no bad characters. It only misses some characters.

In handler, I commented USART_Cmd(...), moved USART_ClearITPendingBit(USART3, USART_IT_RXNE); to the bottom, and changed priority to 0,1,2,3.
However, nothing changed.

My clock is 168MHz and uart uses 9600, or 115200 baudrate.
Both have same problem.

Below is my code.

- For some reasons, I can't use HAL driver.

```
void Uart_Init(long uart_baudrate) {
    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure;
    USART_InitTypeDef USART_InitStructure;

    /* GPIO Periph clock enable */
    RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOB, ENABLE);

    // USART1 Port Configuration (TX - 9, RX - 10)
    GPIO_StructInit(&GPIO_InitStructure);
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_10 | GPIO_Pin_11;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_PP;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_100MHz;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_NOPULL;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStructure);

    /* Connect USART pins to AF */
    GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOB, GPIO_PinSource10, GPIO_AF_USART3);
    GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOB, GPIO_PinSource11, GPIO_AF_USART3);

    RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB1Periph_USART3, ENABLE);

    USART_StructInit(&USART_InitStructure);
    USART_InitStructure.USART_BaudRate = uart_baudrate;
    USART_InitStructure.USART_WordLength = USART_WordLength_8b;
    USART_InitStructure.USART_StopBits = USART_StopBits_1;
    USART_InitStructure.USART_Parity = USART_Parity_No;
    USART_InitStructure.USART_HardwareFlowControl = USART_HardwareFlowControl_None;
    USART_InitStructure.USART_Mode = USART_Mode_Rx | USART_Mode_Tx;

    USART_Init(USART3, &USART_InitStructure);
    USART_Cmd(USART3, ENABLE);
}

#define UART_BUF_LEN 64
volatile static char uartBuffer[UART_BUF_LEN]; 
volatile static int  uartBufferIn = 0;
volatile static int  uartBufferOut = 0;

//Uart rx handler
void USART3_IRQHandler(void){
    unsigned int st1;
    st1 = __disable_interrupts();
    if(USART_GetITStatus(USART3, USART_IT_RXNE) == SET){
        USART_ClearITPendingBit(USART3, USART_IT_RXNE);
        uartBuffer[uartBufferIn] = USART_ReceiveData(USART3);       
        uartBufferIn++;
        if(uartBufferIn==uartBufferOut)uartBufferOut++;
        uartBufferIn&=0x3F;
        uartBufferOut&=0x3F;
    }
    USART_Cmd(USART3, ENABLE);
        __restore_interrupts(st1);
}

//Enable uart rx interrupt
void Uart_Start(void){
    unsigned int st1;
    st1 = __disable_interrupts();

    NVIC_InitTypeDef NVIC_InitStructure;
    VectorTable->USART3_IRQHANDLER = USART3_IRQHandler;
    NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannel = USART3_IRQn;
  NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelPreemptionPriority = 1;
  NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelSubPriority = 1;
  NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelCmd = ENABLE;
  NVIC_Init(&NVIC_InitStructure);
    USART_Cmd(USART3, ENABLE);
    USART_ITConfig(USART3, USART_IT_RXNE, ENABLE);

    __restore_interrupts(st1);
}
```

Comment: The incoming string is like "Ths is tt sring".
How did you find out this exactly?

Comment: @StephenPlyaskin I have a function that display a string(I mean, char[]) on LCD, so I just displayed incoming string on LCD.

Comment: Could you just send data back to USART? And better look at MCU memory with debugger. Maybe some bug in LCD output function.